# What is Bash's string{ending1,ending2} construct called and what is the equivalent in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I've been trying to switch to zsh. Something I've missed so far is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /very/long/path/to/file1.conf{,.old}
#bash expandes that to:
mv /very/long/path/to/file1.conf /very/long/path/to/file1.conf.old
```

What is that called, and is there a zsh equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called *Brace Expansion* and is present also in `zsh`.

One important difference between bash and zsh is that in zsh parameter expansion is performed inside braces, but in bash this is not the case.

Comment: Very strange; it's working for me now. I tried it before and it gave me some error, so I've been avoiding it for a month or so.

Comment: I also got an error and blamed it on zsh. Turned out I was just putting a space after the comma in the braces.